# highlight text in wordpress posts which contain accents

Tags: wordpress, search, character, highlight, radix

In search box some user ask to find "Munchen" (original is München) search will find anyway dont ask me how I don't know.
In wordpress search result i know how to highlight word which is exactly same as search patern, but how to highlight word München. In other words I am looking for some kind of function which will find patern match on base characters.

Answer (score 0):

Off hand, you'd likely have to make an copy of an array of the post contents, replace any ç with c, é with e, etc. Then search the copy returning the index.

That index would be the right position in the originial, ç containing array.